# React bind not working

Tags: reactjs, bind

React newbie here needs help. This is a simple practice app that iterates through an array to output voting cards. I'm getting the dreaded 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined' error but as you can see from my code I've bound it. What am I missing?

```
<body>
    <div id='app'>React has not rendered</div>

    <script type="text/babel">

    class MealPlanner extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.add = this.add.bind(this);
            this.subtract = this.subtract.bind(this);
            this.state = {
                votes: 0
            };
            this.meallist = this.props.list.map(function(meal){
                return <div key={meal.id} className="dinner">
                    <MealPic mealimage={meal.img}/>
                    <h1>{meal.name}</h1>
                    <p>Like</p>
                    <button onClick={this.add}>+1</button>
                    <p>UnLike</p>
                    <button onClick={this.subtract}>-1</button>
                    <div>Total: {this.state.votes}</div>
                    <button onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
                </div>
            });
        }
        add(event){
            this.setState ({
                votes: this.state.votes + 1
            })
        }
        subtract(event){
            this.setState ({
                votes: this.state.votes - 1
            })
        }
        reset(event){
            count: 0
        }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className='wrapper'>
                {this.meallist}
            </div>
        );
    }
    }

    function MealPic(props){
        return(
            <img src={props.mealimage} alt="meal image" className="dinnerimage"/>
        );
    }

    var mealPics = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Meal One', img: "https://static.pexels.com/photos/406152/pexels-photo-406152.jpeg"},
        {id: 2, name: 'Meal Two', img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/566345/pexels-photo-566345.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"},
        {id: 3, name: 'Meal Three', img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/605626/pexels-photo-605626.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"}
    ];

    ReactDOM.render(
        <MealPlanner  list = {mealPics} />,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: this should be in render() instead constructor(): const  meaList = this.props.list.map();

Comment: No. Subtract doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, you had `this.meallist` returning some jsx inside your constructor. You should place this inside of the `render` method.

Because of how Javascript handles `this` inside nested functions, it will take on a new context. The simplest way to avoid this is to use es6 arrow functions.

So `this.props.list.map(function (meal)` becomes `this.props.list.map(meal =>`

Full example below. I would also suggest putting some time into formatting your code some more, it'll help you debug a lot easier when you run into problems.

```
class MealPlanner extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            votes: 0
        };
        this.add = this.add.bind(this);
        this.subtract = this.subtract.bind(this);
    }

    add(event) {
        this.setState({
            votes: this.state.votes + 1
        })
    }

    subtract(event) {
        this.setState({
            votes: this.state.votes - 1
        })
    }

    reset(event) {
        this.setState({ this.state.votes: 0 }}
    }

    render() {
        this.meallist = this.props.list.map(meal => {
            return (
                <div key={meal.id} className="dinner">
                    <MealPic mealimage={meal.img} />
                    <h1>{meal.name}</h1>
                    <p>Like</p>
                    <button onClick={this.add}>+1</button>
                    <p>UnLike</p>
                    <button onClick={this.subtract}>-1</button>
                    <div>Total: {this.state.votes}</div>
                    <button onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
                </div>
            )
        });

        return (
            <div className='wrapper'>
                {this.meallist}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function MealPic(props) {
    return (
        <img src={props.mealimage} alt="meal image" className="dinnerimage" />
    );
}

var mealPics = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Meal One', img: "https://static.pexels.com/photos/406152/pexels-photo-406152.jpeg" },
    { id: 2, name: 'Meal Two', img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/566345/pexels-photo-566345.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" },
    { id: 3, name: 'Meal Three', img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/605626/pexels-photo-605626.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" }
];

ReactDOM.render(
    <MealPlanner list={mealPics} />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: TY! Works like a charm. I really appreciate the help. It's just an exercise but there's a lot of important concepts here. Now if I can just get the reset button working.  ;)

Comment: Thx, again. I had that one solved (but gave you an upvote anyway). My code is a little different but worked.

reset(event) {
            this.setState({
                votes: 0
            })
        }

Answer (score 4):

It is because you have nested function call which take control of the `this` context.

change this line:

```
this.meallist = this.props.list.map(function(meal){
   return...
```

With arrow function to use a lexical context for `this`:

```
this.props.list.map((meal) => {
```

**Edit**
As *Luke M Willis* mentioned in his comment, if for some reason you can't use arrow functions, you can refactor the `map` function to an external function and bind it as well.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    this.subtract = this.subtract.bind(this);
    this.returnMealMarkup = this.returnMealMarkup.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      votes: 0
    };
    this.meallist = this.props.list.map(this.returnMealMarkup);
  }

  returnMealMarkup(meal) {
    return (
      <div key={meal.id} className="dinner">
        <MealPic mealimage={meal.img} />
        <h1>{meal.name}</h1>
        <p>Like</p>
        <button onClick={this.add}>+1</button>
        <p>UnLike</p>
        <button onClick={this.subtract}>-1</button>
        <div>Total: {this.state.votes}</div>
        <button onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
//...
```

**Edit #2**
As a followup to your comment:

> Now I don't get any errors but I also don't have any output.
>   Suggestions?

Don't forget to wrap the `jsx` with `()`, eg: `return (<div></div>);`

```
(meal) => {

      return (
        <div key={meal.id} className="dinner">
          <MealPic mealimage={meal.img} />
          <h1>{meal.name}</h1>
          <p>Like</p>
          <button onClick={this.add}>+1</button>
          <p>UnLike</p>
          <button onClick={this.subtract}>-1</button>
          <div>Total: {this.state.votes}</div>
          <button onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: If you can't use arrow functions for some reason, you can also `bind` the function you pass to `map`.

Comment: @LukeMWillis indeed.

Comment: Hey Sag1v: I tried the fat arrow function. Now I don't get any errors but I also don't have any output. Suggestions? (I should also mention that the React Chrome inspector shows the component being output with the array, but nothing shows up on the screen). I'm too new to know what this means.

Comment: Thx. That worked. Now to hack away at it until I understand why.  ;)

Comment: check my edit#2 you should wrap your `jsx` with parentheses if it's more than 1 line because its an expression.